# remove white space from only beginning of a php string

Tags: php, string, escaping

i have a string like below

`$string = '  florida'`

how can i remove white space from beginning ONLY to form it like below.

`$result_string = 'florida'`

i am sorry if it is too easy question.

Comment: i said sorry in the first hand, anyway thanks for taking interest guyz

Comment: we can find everything on google so what is the use of stackoverflow ?

Comment: thts y i accepted an answer with downvote...cheers

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$string = ' florida'

$result_string = ltrim($string);

echo $result_string;// it will remove white spces from beganing
```

Comment: this worked just fine for me, i dont know why u down-voted it

Answer (score 9):

sounds like [`ltrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) is what you're looking for:

> Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) It removes leading and trailing whitespaces

Manual:

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

**Edit**, ltrim (as mentioned by Oezi) removes the beginning whitespace (missed that part)

Comment: the question explicitly says "_only from the beginning_".

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

$string = trim('  florida');

echo $string; // florida

For more informations: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Please read the other answers before posting. The exact same suggestion has already been made 6 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11097376/10743426